# Unable to resolve new_devices which is of type ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

My Java code is here and Error is shown in line: ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices)

new_devices is added activity_main.xml

I'm new to android application development, plz help.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sample;

All imports added here     

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    Button btn;
    BluetoothDevice BTdevice;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter;  /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(btn);

    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        //updateTime();
        final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(bluetoothAdapter != null)
        {
            //btArrayAdapter.clear();
            Log.d("ARRAY ADAPTER"," I AM INITIALIZED ");

            if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering())
            {
                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            }
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
            {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
            updateTime();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            Log.d("Discovery","Completed Discovery");
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND); 
            Log.d("Intent Filter","After Intent filter call");
            registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver, filter);
            Log.d("Intent Filter","After Register recieve call");
        }
        else
        {
            AlertDialog alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertdialog.setTitle("Bluetooth Adapter");
            alertdialog.setMessage("Bluetooth not supported in the device");

        }

        ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
        btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        newDevicesListView.setAdapter(btArrayAdapter);
        //btDevList.setAdapter(btArrayAdapter);
        // Register the BroadcastReceiver
        //registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));


    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("Broadcastreciever","Inside Broadcast reciever");
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d("Broadcastreciever","After Getaction");

            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
            {
                Log.d("Broadcastreciever","Inside Action found");
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Log.d("Broadcastreciever","After get Parcelable");
                btArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress()); //Found Crash here
                Log.d("Broadcastreciever","After get Device address");
                btArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d("Broadcastreciever","After notify data changed");
            }
        }
    };



Activity_Main.xml looks like this:

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <ListView
        //android:id="@+id/new_devices"
        android:id="@+id/android:new_devices" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this error cause you don't have ListView with id "new_devices". Your setContentView should point to your layout, like setContentView(R.layout.activity_main), and your ListView on this layout should have id like @+id/new_devices.

Comment: I have changed the setContentView(R.layout.activity_main). Eventhough i have @+id/new_devices in my activity_main.xml it is showing an error. Is there anything wrong this layout xml ? <ListView
        android:id="@+id/new_devices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
        />

Answer (score 0):

The way android works is, whenever you will create ids in xml and build the project, it will add those ids in R.java. You can then access same ids in your classes.

Now every id is associated with a View, and whenever you are using the id you shall make sure that your view is populated. (This will avoid NUllPointerException).

In your code above views will not be populated as you are not using setContentView in onCreate. And setContentView(which populates Views) shall be used before accessing any View..

Change your onCreate to:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Rest of the code
    }
```

Also, in your Activity_Main.xml 1) change the name to activity_main.xml in case its not, and then change the code of ListView as follows:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/new_devices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </ListView>
```

Save your Xmls, go to Project->Clean All Projects, and then Projects->Build the Project.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This helps to resolve the issues.Eventhough i'm still not able to view the BT devices list in the listview. Thanks.